# Map new MS Teams channels to existing folders (am i doing things correctly)

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

We have a SharePoint modern team site which contain a document library with 2 folders "General" & "test", as follow:-

[image]

but when i access this sharepoint site inside MS Teams, i can only see the "General" folder as follow:-

[image]

so is it fine/recommnded if inside MS Team >> i create a new Channel >> named it "test" >> so the new channel will get mapped automatically to the test folder inside sharepoint document library ? so i will have my MS Teams as follow:-

[image]

I am doing so as the user asked us to have all the main folders under the Software Development title (on the same level as the General channel), so he do not have to click on General to access the main folder.. so is creating new MS Teams channel for each main folder a valid approach ? or it have drawbacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Channels are dedicated sections within a team to keep conversations organized by specific topics, projects, disciplines-whatever works for your team. So if your organization needs to work on each main folder, I think it is feasible to create separate channel for each main folder.

Comment: in our case we do not care about conversation,, what we need is to list all the folders directly under the team site name (similar to the General tab/folder),, so i can not find any way to do so other than adding new channels with the same names as the main folders.. will my approach work?